# SQL | Change date to date+time

Tags: sql, pgadmin

So I have been trying to fix this problem and other Stackoverflow don't seem to do it for me

I have a column called "entered" with the datatype: "date". I would like to change the datatype from date to date+time. All post are saying to use:

ALTER TABLE (table)
ALTER COLUMN (column) timestamp

But then I get the following error:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "timestamp"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 44

For the record, the table currently has data and I cant simply copy and drop it

Comment: `ALTER TABLE the_table ALTER COLUMN the_column TYPE timestamp USING the_column::timestamp;`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you posted should work for SQL Server / MS Access.
In Oracle SQL, I have used the below SQL syntax to change the data type of a column. I am not sure if this was one of the other suggestions that did not work. Hope this works for you.

```
alter table
   your_table_name
modify
(
   your_column_name    datetime
);
```